# Fetch 'Copyright' info field for an exe using commandline in Windows Server 2016

Tags: powershell, cmd, file-properties

I am interested in getting the 'Copyright' information field using the cmd or PowerShell. Manually, it can be accessed by

`RighClick the executable -> Properties -> Details -> Copyright`

I am aware of the `wmic datafile` command,

> wmic datafile where Name="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" get
>   Manufacturer,Name,Version

but it does *not* give most of the detailed information from the `Details` tab in the file properties.

How do I get this info using cmd or PowerShell? I believe Python should be able to solve it easily, but sometimes it is not an option to install python on production server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Powershell actually gives you a plethora of information in the VersionInfo property.

```
(Get-Item "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe").VersionInfo.LegalCopyright
```

Here is a technet article with more information if you need it.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/12/07/how-to-correctly-check-file-versions-with-powershell/

Comment: how did I miss this when searching for the issue...
Anyhow, this is what I needed. I will look into VersionInfo to see what other options does it have. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us.